# show and hide div row in css

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
#table{
    display:table;
}   
#table div.row{
    display:table-row;
}
#table div.row div{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    text-align:right;
}
#table div.row:first-child{
    color:white;
    background-color:blue;
}
#table div.row:last-child{
    color:white;
    background-color:green;
}

#table div.row:last-child{
    display:none;
}
#table div.row:hover{
    display:table-row;
}
</style>

<div id='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div>CELL</div><div>CELL</div><div>CELL</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div>CELL</div><div>CELL</div><div>CELL</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I cant get rid off to my assignment, where in, we will make a 2 rows of table where in the default view is only one row, because the last row was hidden (display:none), then when you hover the mouse in the table the second row will appear, I don’t know what is the error of my CSS?,  do you think this line of CSS is the source of my error #table div.row:hover{ display:table-row;}, thank you for expaining me.

[here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8P5w9/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> then when you hover the mouse **in the table** the second row will appear

So why not do that:

```
#table:hover .row:last-child {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Also i would suggest to just use the [table tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp). It doesn't bring extra troubles with them and gives a much better oversight.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p698V/)

---

[Example with the table tags](http://jsfiddle.net/p698V/1/)

Comment: yeah! I notice that .row is the same of div.row

Comment: Yea :) In your example every `.row` is a div. It is not neccesary and it will only slow the selector down when you specify the element :)

Comment: thanks again master nkmol, ahh out of my question, what do u call this in css +(plus sign)? thanks

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion It's called a Adjacent sibling selector. `This selector allows you to select an element that is directly after another specific element.` Here a good article about selectors: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

```
#table div.row:hover + div.row:last-child{
    display:table-row;
}
```

This will work. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Comment: can you explain what is that plus + sign thank you sir goutham2027

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
#table:hover div.row:last-child {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the event actives when mouse enter inside `#table`. I know you are asking with css, but I made a javascript option if you would use it:

JS

```
    $("#table")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find("div.row:last-child").css({'display':'table-row'});
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find("div.row:last-child").css({'display':'none'});
    });
```

Here you have a [link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/3Dy77/) with your example.

Comment: sorry im too noob I cant handle that script :-(

Comment: Don't worry, in fact, is much better css than js, it's faster. So you are right! =)